# get the values from checkboxes those were created dynamically C# JQuery Asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have these checkboxes those are created dynamically using C#. These are HTMLInputCheckboxes. They are kept under a panel called "panel_seat".
[image]

I want to get the values from these checkboxes to post them in database. How to do this? Either creating them as checkbox list or group?

If so please give me some code references please.

Comment: Check_0,check_1...etc.., are the ids

Comment: You would have to give them all the same name `name="check[]"` .. the rest will be handled by your server or by `.serialize()`.

Comment: One approach would be to utilize *Ajax*.  Then you contact a *Server-Side Event / Service*. This will allow you to use *JavaScript* or *jQuery* to push your Client-Side object to Server-Side.  Then you would be able to simply *Serialize* / *Deserialize* the data back and forth with *Json*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn_check").click(function () {
            var str = "";
            x = $("#frm").serializeArray();
             str = JSON.stringify(x);

            $('#<%=hdnSelectedTicket.ClientID %>').val(str);


        });
    });
```

Asp.net:

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectedTicket"  runat="server" />
```

C# code: Using special dll for Json

```
 using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
 namespace TestApp.components.seatfromdb
{
public class Test
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

}

public partial class seatfromdb : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     

 }

    protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<Test> myDeserializedObjList = (List<Test>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(hdnSelectedTicket.Value, typeof(List<Test>));
        int count = myDeserializedObjList.Count;
        string[] chkarr = new string[count-4];
        int j=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (myDeserializedObjList[i].name.Substring(0, 6) == "check_")
            {
                chkarr[j] = myDeserializedObjList[i].name.Substring(6,1);
                j++;
            }
        }

    }


}
```

}

Checkbox group or list is not needed. I Used hidden field which carries the (stringified checkbox values) Json. charr[] array can be put into the database as by our need either as bytes or anything else.